# How do I delete duplicates based on a condition? Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, conditional-statements, delete-row

So I have a df that looks something like this:

```
Person_ID    Procedure_ID   Date(d/m/y)
34           30             03/03/2011
34           30             02/03/2011
32           19             01/01/2020
34           32             01/04/2012
```

If a Person_ID has the same procedure twice or more, like that  34 - 30 case above, the code needs to keep only the newest row, deleting all the others. In the example I gave the expected result would be:

```
Person_ID    Procedure_ID   Date(d/m/y)
34           30             02/03/2011
32           19             01/01/2020
34           32             01/04/2012
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df.sort_values(by='Date(d/m/y)',ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['Person_ID','Procedure_ID'])`

Comment: Never thought of using ascend to drop duplicates, thank you it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby `'Person_ID', 'Procedure_ID'` and get the last element from each group.

**Code**

```
df.sort_values(by='Date(d/m/y)').groupby(['Person_ID', 'Procedure_ID'], as_index=False).last()
```

**Output**

```
Person_ID   Procedure_ID    Date(d/m/y)
0   32      19              01/01/2020
1   34      30              02/03/2011
2   34      32              01/04/2012
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't know about this last() command. It kinda worked, it does not return the newest date consistently doe.

Comment: you would have to sort first for that

Comment: updated the code.